# Telerik Datetime picker- Time shows 30 minutes span

Tags: telerik-datepicker

```
@Html.Telerik().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.DepartureTime).Value(Model.DepartureTime > DateTime.MinValue ? Model.DepartureTime : DateTime.Today).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("OnChangeDatePicker"))
```

In `Telerik` datetime picker, The Time is 30 minutes span. Like 9, 9.30, 10, 10.30 etc. Is there a way to select time For each minutes eg: 9.00, 9.01,9.02 etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation for what you are looking for:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-datetimepicker-configuration.html#Interval

Basically you want to set the `Interval` configuration option to `1` such as.

```
@Html.Telerik().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.DepartureTime)
               .Interval(1)
               .Value(Model.DepartureTime > DateTime.MinValue ? Model.DepartureTime : DateTime.Today)
               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("OnChangeDatePicker"))
```

Now I havent tested this exact scenario but the documentation speaks for itself.

Cheers, Nico